# After installing java8 via Homebrew, JAVA_HOME is incorrect

Tags: java, java-8, homebrew

I am installing the android sdk on my mac via homebrew. First I ran

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

and it told me to install java8 as well:

```
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java8
```

Now, when I try to run the sdkmanager, I get this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

Obviously I have to edit JAVA_HOME in my `.bash_profile` file. Where should it point?

Every question I've found on SO and other sites simply says to "Point to the JDK, not the JRE." Also I can find default java installation directories from oracle guides, etc. But nothing about java8 from homebrew.

Comment: It says: _Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in **your environment**_.  Emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/), but I installed this cask so I could answer:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So you can do that, **or** in sdkman, you could use

```
sdk install java 8.0.181-oracle
```

and then either set it as the default there *or* issue a

```
sdk use java 8.0.181-oracle
```

or whatever java you need (like `sdk use java 10.0.1-oracle`) for the session.

Comment: That did it! What is the purpose of pointing it at the Contents/Home directory? What is JAVA_HOME actually used for?

Comment: @whiterook6 That's where the files are. You can open that folder in the terminal and look. It's (mainly) used to determine relative paths for executables in the `bin` subfolder, but there are additional paths (like the `lib` subfolder) that might also be used.